# Location of /Downloads folder for devices with and without SD card

Tags: android

Please let me know what are default locations for `Downloads` folder on devices with and without SD card.

And how can I check if particular phone doesn't have SD card.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check and see if a device has an SD card, you use: `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` if you don't have an SD card, you use: `Environment.getDataDirectory()`

Essentially, if there is no SD card, you can create your own directory on the device locally. I've listed some code that might help:

```
/*
             * This sections checks the phone to see if there is a SD card. if
             * there is an SD card, a directory is created on the SD card to
             * store the test log results. If there is not a SD card, then the
             * directory is created on the phones internal hard drive
             */
                    //if there is no SD card, create new directory objects to make directory on device
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
                            //create new file directory object
                directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                        + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
                photoDirectory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                        + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");
                /*
                 * this checks to see if there are any previous test photo files
                 * if there are any photos, they are deleted for the sake of
                 * memory
                 */
                if (photoDirectory.exists()) {
                    File[] dirFiles = photoDirectory.listFiles();
                    if (dirFiles.length != 0) {
                        for (int ii = 0; ii <= dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                            dirFiles[ii].delete();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if no directory exists, create new directory
                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdir();
                }

                // if phone DOES have sd card
            } else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
                // search for directory on SD card
                directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
                photoDirectory = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");
                if (photoDirectory.exists()) {
                    File[] dirFiles = photoDirectory.listFiles();
                    if (dirFiles.length > 0) {
                        for (int ii = 0; ii < dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                            dirFiles[ii].delete();
                        }
                        dirFiles = null;
                    }
                }
                // if no directory exists, create new directory to store test
                // results
                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdir();
                }
            }// end of SD card checking
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the internal download location.

To programmatically obtain the external download location, use:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Downloads/"
```

Or at least, that is what is it on my HTC EVO 4G.

For my app, i developed a simple class that detected the current state of the SD Card, simplified into human-understood terms. It can be easily done using

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState()
```

and comparing it to the various default states, defined under the `Environment` class. The important ones are `Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED` and `Environment.MEDIA_SHARED`. The first (i believe) tells you if there is any external storage at all and the second tells you if it is mounted or not.

Note: when comparing the states, use .equals as they are strings, not integers like most state objects in Android.

Comment: sometime the name of the download folder can change depending on the device you should use something like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+ "/"` to get the path of the downloads folder