# How to get exact path of a folder created in storage of phone

Tags: android, storage

I use this code line to create folder in storage of phone:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + "Books");

boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdir();
}
```

how i get path of that folder to add books in that folder programatically.i use this line to get folder path but it just give path till storage...

```
destination = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Books";
```

i want the path of books folder exactly...

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724706/how-to-get-my-android-device-internal-download-folder-path

Answer (score 1):

**Try this,**

```
folder.getAbsolutePath();
```

this will return you absolute path of file