# How to store current time to an external storage?

Tags: java, android

I have written a function to get current time

while calling this function in another function i am getting the current time in Logcat. Can any one help me how to store this in an external storage in android studio.

Note: I have added 
 in manifest.xml .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location of /Downloads folder for devices with and without SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351840/location-of-downloads-folder-for-devices-with-and-without-sd-card)

Comment: Please check the official docs on saving data: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "time.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            String currentTime = "";//call here your method which gives you current time
            pw.println(currentTime);
            pw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Don't forget to add permission

Comment: For current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format text, use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html): `Instant.now().toString()` ➙ `2018-10-06T23:22:09.827625Z`. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.